# Display the existing image in edit form and update it using laravel

Tags: forms, laravel

I am able to display the existing text like name and address but unable to display Image in edit form.
My show.blade.php

```
 @section('content')
        <p>This is user {{ $profile->name }}</p>
        <p>This is address {{ $profile->address }}</p>
         <img src= "/storage/images/{{ $profile->images }}" style="width:504px;height:228px />     
 @endsection
```

this works  fine.

now edit.blade.php

```
<div class="container">
  <form method="POST" action="/profiles/{{$profile->id}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ method_field('PATCH') }}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group">
    name  <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ $profile->name }}" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     address  <input type="textarea" name="address" value="{{ $profile->address }}" />
    </div> 
    <div class="form-group">
    @if ("/storage/images/{{ $profile->images }}")
        <img src="{{ $profile->image }}">
    @else
            <p>No image found</p>
    @endif
        image <input type="file" name="image" value="{{ $profile->images }}"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>``

</div>
```

when I try to save the  form a diffrent images path is saved in database table when updating the images ie

```
 /tmp/phpHs0Io6
```

store  controller is

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
       $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
         'address' => 'nullable' ,
    ]);
       $profile = new profile;
       $profile-> user_id = auth()->id();
       $profile-> name = $request->name;
       $profile-> address = $request->address;         
       $request->image->store('public/images');
       $path = $request->image->hashName();
       $profile-> images = $path;
       $profile->save();
       return redirect('/home');
}
```

and update controller is

```
public function update(Request $request, profile $profile)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
             'address' => 'nullable' ,
        ]);
           $profile->update($request->all());
           $profile-> name = $request->name;
           $profile-> address = $request->address;         
           $request->image->store('public/images');
           $path = $request->image->hashName();
           $profile-> images = $path;
           $profile->save();
           return redirect('/home');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all before you save an image you have to check if user uploaded one; Your way of saving image is wrong use this pattern;

```
    public function update(Request $request, profile $profile)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
             'address' => 'nullable' ,
        ]);
           $profile->update($request->all());
           $profile-> name = $request->name;
           $profile-> address = $request->address;         

           if(Input::hasFile('image')){
           $file = Input::file('image');
           $destinationPath = public_path(). '/uploads/';
           $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
           $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);

          //then proceeded to save user
          $profile-> images =           
          $destinationPath.$filename;
          $profile->save();
          return redirect('/home');
          }else{


           $profile->save();
           return redirect('/home');
        }
}
```

same on update function.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly writing path in if condition, use `file_exists` function to check whether your image exist at the given location. For more info check this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)

Answer (score 0):

i am a bit late but i have a suggestion:
so if ur image is being uploaded in storage this code might work, u still need to resize image so its not over the whole site:

```
                                <div class="pull-right">
                                    <label for="image">Choosen Datei:</label>
                                    <img src="{{Storage::disk('local')->url($profile->image)}}" alt="">
                                    <label for="image"
                                        >Choose data</label
                                    >
                                    <input
                                        type="file"
                                        name="image"
                                        id="image"
                                        class="form-control"
                                    />
                                </div>
```